# How to extract the elements from csv to json in S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

- I need to find the csv files from the folder
- List all the files inside the folder
- Convert files to json and save in the same bucket

Csv file, Like below so many csv files are there

```
emp_id,Name,Company
10,Aka,TCS
11,VeI,TCS
```

Code is below

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket('testfolder')
    for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
        print(file.key)
    for csv_f in file.key:
        with open(f'{csv_f.replace(".csv", ".json")}', "w") as f:
            pd.read_csv(csv_f).to_json(f, orient='index')
```

Not able to save if you remove bucket name it will save in the folder. How to save back to bucket name

Comment: Hi. Can you provide example of input csv file/data?

Comment: @Marcin I have given

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: Yes, not writing  into bucket if use normal csvdicreader. for pandas I am getting No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath

Comment: From the code it seems that it's saving on your local disk, you need to call a function to upload it to s3, something like `s3.upload_file(f.name, bucket_name, object_name)`.

Comment: @geckos any link, i m new to aws

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-uploading-files.html  Double check the file, bucket and object names

Comment: Did you create your own lambda layer or package to have panda in lambda?

Comment: @Marcin yes i have done that, pandas and numpy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the following code:

```
from io import StringIO

import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    
    input_bucket = 'bucket-with-csv-file-44244'
    
    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(input_bucket)
    
    for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
        
        if file.key.endswith(".csv"):
           
            csv_f = f"s3://{input_bucket}/{file.key}"
            
            print(csv_f)
            
            json_file = file.key.replace(".csv", ".json")
            
            print(json_file)
            
            json_buffer = StringIO()
            
            df = pd.read_csv(csv_f)
            
            df.to_json(json_buffer, orient='index')
            
            s3.Object(input_bucket, json_file).put(Body=json_buffer.getvalue())
```

Your lambda layer will need to have:

```
fsspec
pandas
s3fs
```

Comment: can i ask fsspec and s3fs. what is the use

Comment: @aysh To read from s3. Panda can read directly from s3. Should be also able to write as well, but in my tests now, I didn't write.

Comment: One last question why we need to convert stringI0. Sorry If i am disturbing you  json_buffer = StringIO()  and put(Body=json_buffer.getvalue())  I didnt get the info of using the line

Comment: @aysh This is a workaround. Normally panda should be able to write to s3. But in my tests it did not. Maybe you will have more luck. The alternative and more traditional way of writing to s3 is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40615630/248823) which involves StringIO.

Comment: if i want to give one different bucket name to save df.to_json(json_buffer, orient='index'). can i given parameter here. or do i need to create a function as upload_file() , i need to pass the bucket name

Comment: @aysh in `s3.Object(input_bucket, json_file)` you can change `input_bucket` to something else.

Comment: can you answer below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63618932/how-to-read-content-from-the-s3-bucket-as-url